# How to create multiple reocrds of Ext.data.Model

Tags: extjs4.2

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('mObject', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'text',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'x',   type: 'int', convert: null},
        {name: 'y', type: 'int', convert: null}
    ]
});

var obj = Ext.create('mObject', {
    text   : 'test test',
    x : 100,
    y  : 24
});
```

How can I add more records? and is there any way to go to a specific record by a field value, I mean if I have 200 records and I ant to navigate to a record with name='yaya' do I have to go through all records and search for 'yaya' or there is alternative way?

Comment: you can use json structure for storing multiple records in model and store.

Comment: Any hint, link? thank you very much...:-)

Comment: see this link.http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/array-grid.js May be it will helpful to you.

Comment: you can put your 200 records into a store and use the [store.findBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy) method

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

```
Ext.define('mObject', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'text',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'x',   type: 'int', convert: null},
        {name: 'y', type: 'int', convert: null}
    ]}
});
var mObject=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'mObject',
     data : []
 });
 mObject.add({text: 'sample1', x: 34, y:544});
 mObject.add({text: 'sample2', x: 243, y:76});
 mObject.add({text: 'sample3', x: 54, y:123});
 mObject.add({text: 'sample4', x: 67, y:43});
 mObject.add({text: 'sample5', x: 12, y:655});

 var indx=mObject.find('text','sample4');
 alert( mObject.getAt(indx).get('text'));
```